# Резервное копирование СУБД PostgreSQL

Tags: linux, база-данных, postgresql

Есть сервер (linux suse) на котором установлена СУБД PostgreSQL, подключиться к БД возможно только с использованием ssh. Возникла необходимость автоматического резервного копирования базы данных на другой удаленный сервер (linux centOS). Каким образом лучше всего организовать автоматическое копирование?

Comment: [pg_dump](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/11/app-pgdump) и [cron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вопросе бекапа potgresql есть две принципиальные возможности:

### Логический бекап

Штатными утилитами [`pg_dump` и `pg_dumpall`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html). Логический бекап - это текст запросов, которые воссоздадут вашу базу данных. Из чего следует, что это:

- медленное восстановление. Данные будут скопированы довольно быстро, но вот индексы и прочие ограничения будут строиться ничего не зная о том что это бекап и будут проверять действительность ограничений
- восстановление возможно только на момент начала копирования каждой из баз через `pg_dump` (`pg_dumpall` вызывает `pg_dump` для каждой из баз кластера)
- компактно. Обычно заметную часть объёма базы данных занимают индексы. Которые в логическом дампе представлены только командами создания этих индексов. А так же текст хорошо сжимается. Поэтому логический дамп может быть спокойно в 10 раз меньше объёма базы
- можно сохранять только некоторые базы данных, можно не сохранять некоторые таблицы
- текстовый формат `plain` - просто текст запросов, из него данные можно достать хоть текстовым редактором.
- форматы `custom` и `directory` с другой стороны можно восстанавливать параллельно в несколько потоков (а `directory` и снимать в несколько потоков) - что позволяет сократить время восстановления. А так же из этих форматов можно восстанавливать отдельные объекты базы, например, только одну таблицу.

`pg_dump` и `pg_dumpall` могут работать по сети. Единственное что необходимо - версия утилиты на бекап-машине должна быть такая же или новее чем на самой СУБД. При том нет ограничения по major версии. `pg_dump` версии 11.4 может корректно снимать бекап с версии условно 9.3.12 (и вообще до 7.0 релиза)

Восстанавливать можно так же на разный версиях postgresql.

### Физический бекап

Другая возможность - использовать физическую копию базы. `pg_basebackup` либо другие её реализации.

- есть возможность выбрать момент, на который восстанавливать базу с точностью до конкретной транзакции. Для этого необходим basebackup снятый до необходимой точки восстановления и [непрерывный архив WAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html)
- такой бекап занимает много места. Если заинтересованы в восстановлении на произвольную точку времени (PitR) - то архив WAL тем более занимает сложно предсказуемый объём
- это копия только всего экземпляра postgresql. Строго все базы с этого экземпляра, ничего исключить нельзя. И объём точно равный объёму базы.
- восстановление представляет собой простое файловое копирование и затем запуск базы. По объёму данных копировать много, но операция простая, в большинстве своём крупными файлами
- однако восстановление в произвольный момент времени требует обработать все WAL от начала basebackup до необходимой точки. И это может быть весьма не быстро
- восстановление возможно только используя ту же самую major версию базы и не ниже того же самого minor релиза

Работать так же может по сети без проблем. Вообще помимо бекапов так ещё реплики поднимают.

---

Затем владелец базы думает, необходимо ли ему восстановление в произвольную точку времени и готов ли он к такому большому объёму данных в бекапе либо достаточно например ежесуточных логических дампов. Затем определяетесь сколько копий хранить.

Можно использовать оба подхода, например, делать архив WAL глубиной в неделю со снятием basebackup в понедельник/четверг, в субботу делать `pg_dump` и хранить логический дамп ещё полгода.

Непосредственно по настройке выбранного плана резервного копирования:

- pg_dump обычно удобно делать просто из крона с отправкой оповещения о ошибках на почту.
- для basebackup вручную собирать корректную процедуру ведения архива не так просто, имеет смысл использовать специализированные системы вроде [`wal-g`](https://github.com/wal-g/wal-g) (крайне прост, если бекапить надо на `S3`), [`pgbackrest`](https://pgbackrest.org/), [`barman`](https://www.pgbarman.org/)